# angular2-swing with ionic not work on some smartphone

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I try to build my app with Ionic 2 and for this i use tinder card like this : https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-tinder-cards/
But on some android device ( sony z4 compact, sony z5 compact and HUAWEI P8 lite) next card not load.

The array which contain card is `this.cards` I try to display it with log and it contain the good value. The card display only after click on button for display menu. Or it can work if used button which call voteUp(true/false) function swipe, in theory call the same function but the result is totaly different.
My code :

ts file

```
addNewCards(count: number) {
  this.auth.getToken().subscribe(data=>{
  let url='http://my.url/api/api.php/'+data+'/repas/' + count;
    let result= this.http.get(url).map(data => data.json().msg)
    this.cache.loadFromObservable('repas'+count, result)
    .subscribe(msgs => {
      for (let val of msgs){
        this.cards.push(val[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

template file :

```
<div swing-stack #myswing1 [stackConfig]="stackConfig"   (throwoutleft)="voteUp(false)" (throwoutright)="voteUp(true)" id="card-stack">
    <ion-card class="card" #mycards1 swing-card *ngFor="let c of cards">
      <div *ngIf="c.photo" class=" image-recipe-position">
        <div class="img-recipe"   [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + c.photo + ')'}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ion-item >
        <h2>{{c.title}}</h2>
        {{c.ing}}
      </ion-item>
        <ion-row  >
          <ion-col col-4 offset-1 class="center-left">
            <button disabled={{buttonDisabled}}   (click)="voteUp(false)" class="button-choose">
              <ion-icon class="dislike" name="ios-close"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="center-right" col-4 offset-2>

            <button disabled={{buttonDisabled}}   (click)="voteUp(true)" class="button-choose">
              <ion-icon class="like" name="ios-checkmark"></ion-icon>

            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-card>

  </div>
```

Comment: The angular plugin which is used are [swing](https://github.com/gajus/swing)

Comment: But you should carefully read the tags before slapping them on a question. That API has nothing to do with the Swing tag as defined here, which is part of the Java based desktop computer GUI toolkit.

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: if the card load normaly there are this log `W/cr_Ime: updateState: type [0->0], flags [0], show [false],` and when the card not load there are no log